# How to mount ext2 fs?

Tags: embedded-linux, mount, busybox, ext2

fdisk is used to create mmcblk0p3 on the 64G SD card.

```
Disk /dev/mmcblk0: 63.8 GB, 63864569856 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 7764 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes

        Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks  Id System
/dev/mmcblk0p1   *           2           6       40162+  c Win95 FAT32 (LBA)
/dev/mmcblk0p2               7         130      996030  83 Linux
/dev/mmcblk0p3             131        7764    61320105  83 Linux
```

The fs is then formatted like this:

```
$ mke2fs -L media /dev/mmcblk0p3
Filesystem label=media
OS type: Linux
Block size=4096 (log=2)
Fragment size=4096 (log=2)
3833856 inodes, 15330026 blocks
766501 blocks (5%) reserved for the super user
First data block=0
Maximum filesystem blocks=16777216
468 block groups
32768 blocks per group, 32768 fragments per group
8192 inodes per group
Superblock backups stored on blocks:
    32768, 98304, 163840, 229376, 294912, 819200, 884736, 1605632, 2654208, ...
```

Mount point /media definitely exists and `$ mount /dev/mmcblk0p3 /media` works fine when mmcblk0p3 is a FAT32 FS on a Win95 FAT32 partition. I need to change from FAT32 to ext2 since the FAT32 partition 3 is too easily hosed in this embedded Linux target (power cycle, USB mass storage disconnects, etc.). An Ubuntu 10.04 desktop system has been used to verify that the partition type is ext2 and is able to mount the SD card partition but this needs to work on the embedded Linux target. The kernel version is 2.6.32-17-ridgerun with BusyBox v1.18.2.

- Why does `$ mount /dev/mmcblk0p3 /media` cause `mount: mounting /dev/mmcblk0p3 on /media failed: Invalid argument?`
- Why does `mount -t ext2 /dev/mmcblk0p3 /media` cause `mount: mounting /dev/mmcblk0p3 on /media failed: No such device?`

Comment: Have you checked  if you have ext2 module with lsmod ?

Comment: @pmod I am not in the office today but isn't `mke2fs` the same as `mkfs.ext2?` Either way, I'll check with lsmod on Monday.

Comment: Aside from your problems, it's not clear that ext2 is actually all that superior a choice in light of your concerns - you might want something that is journaling or flash optimized?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why does $ mount /dev/mmcblk0p3 /media cause mount: mounting
>   /dev/mmcblk0p3 on /media failed: Invalid argument?

The kernel can probably mount the filesystem, but it wrongly guess its type.

> Why does mount -t ext2 /dev/mmcblk0p3 /media cause mount: mounting
>   /dev/mmcblk0p3 on /media failed: No such device?

If, after you specified -t, you get a problem like that, it is very likely that the kernel cannot mount the requested filesystem for you. Check if there is a module for that filesystem and it is loaded.

```
lsmod          # show modules
modprobe ext2  # load module
```

Sources : http://www.silas.net.br/doc.notes/unix/linux/busybox-troubleshooting.html

As far as I know `ext2` modules are already loaded by default. But it won't hurt to check.
The problem here I think is the ambiguity due to [mke2fs](http://linux.die.net/man/8/mke2fs). `mke2fs` can be used to create ext2/ext3/ext4 filesystems. You have to specify the file system via `-t` option. Try doing this :

```
#mkfs -t ext2 /dev/hda1
#mkfs.ext2 /dev/hda1
```

You missed out `-t` option in your command making `mke2fs` format it with filesystem in default conf.

Comment: Especially with an embedded kernel, it's not a given that the ext2 driver is loaded as a module, or was even built as a module or that the module is available on a mounted filesystem for the running device to load.  It's also possible that it could have been compiled into the kernel rather than as a module.  Finding the build config (/proc/config.gz if available or elsewhere) would be a good start.  Another test would be to make a tiny ext2 filesystem image and try to loop mount it.

Comment: Thanks a million! modprobe ext2 returned `modprobe: module ext2 not found in modules.dep`. I had `CONFIG_MKFS_EXT2=y` but not `CONFIG_EXT2_FS=y`. CONFIG_MKFS_EXT2 is in the busybox config settings but CONFIG_EXT2_FS is in the Kernel config settings. I was sure I had both of these set, but apparently didn't. Don't know if ext2 will improve my fs issues but hope so. This version of busybox has no mkfs ext3 or mkfs jffs2 so ext2 is my only alternative to FAT32 for now. This target needs to be able to mkfs it's 3rd partition.